# 2 vectors difference to rotation

Tags: c#, parent-child, unity-game-engine

I've been hanging my head around this issue for some time now and I'm at the top of my head not figuring this out.

The issue:

Currently trying to do a fake "swing" moment. Where I have the player object becoming a child to an object you can latch onto during a keypush.

With this in mind, I need to get the correct rotation on the grappleobject, making the velocity of the player becoming the correct rotation on the grappleobject.

This is not meant to be 2D, but 3D. Which causes this headache.

http://img843.imageshack.us/img843/7434/rotations.jpg

I figured that if I could get the vector of position, and the vector of the direction where the player is going towards, as in velocity of the character motor, to get an unique Vector, and this vector info should be able to rotate the grappleobject correctly.

However, that's what I thought was easy, but I've been hacking at this for hours to get that vector difference to do the rotation as it was thought out to be.

tl:dr

2 Vectors, the difference of these two to one vector, this vector controls the rotation of grappleobject to "fake" a swing motion with the proper velocity.

Thank you in advance if there'll be an answer.

Added Info:

Current testings has been these.

///

Parent Orb is the grappleobjects which updates its transform depending on trigger events.
CurDirection is where the player is heading within the vector in world.
CurPos is where the player is at that point in time within the world.

```
 CurDirection = (transform.position-ParentOrb.position);
 CurDirection.Normalize();

 motor.movement.velocity = (CurDirection);
 CurPos = transform.position;
```

////

Also tried out to get the angle from the grappleobject to the player.

///

otherDirection = The direction of velocity in space.
 OtherDirectionPre = Current position in space.

```
 Vector3 targetDir = otherDirection;
 Vector3 forward = otherDirectionPre;

 angle = Vector3.Angle(targetDir, forward);
```

///
I assume these may not be helpful, but better to show where I have gotten so far.

Answer (score 1):

I think you know the radius between the hit point and the center, let's call it r. With the velocity v of the player and the angular velocity ω (=omega) of the axis the player should be connected to you have the vector equation:

v = ω × r

Assuming all 3 vectors are perpendicular to each other you have  ω = v / r.

**EDIT:** You get the radius r from the position of the center and the point of contact of your collision:

```
Vector3 r = collision.contacts[0].point - center;
float radius = r.magnitude;
float angularSpeed = rigidbody.veloctiy.magnitude / radius;
```

Comment: Sadly, my math is pretty subpar which makes this help too hard for me to understand currently. I never went much into radians back in my school days. I started to use Unity 3d not too long ago so still getting into it so mostly a newbie to this.

Comment: I'm sure that Radius will help out but I am not sure still how.   To give you a insight how far off I am, I'll give the two current prototype script. This is VERY early work, mind you.   I did not kid when I said I am new to 3D World thinking, Mostly did 2D before.   These are the scripts. http://www.vdxretrotainment.eu/CurrentScripts.zip  I have current other issues but the main thing is the Grapple that's priority on to get fixed. I did not kid on my math also. ><